# Best practice: stop cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, terminate

we're using google cloud functions triggered by the data storage to add date to big query and spanner databases. 
There are some cases where the cloud function gets triggered but we don't have to do anything. The code in place looks like this:

```
if true:
   # start processing
else: 
   sys.exit('ok')
```

I'm not really sure if sys.exit('ok') is the best way to use here. It's spamming the logs with tons of erros and I could also imagine that it forces cold starts for the next trigger (correct me if i'm wrong).

Is there any best practice to deal with it? Will the execution of the function will stop if I have only a log in my else condition or do I have to tell the function that its job is done now?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If your code has nothing to do when a function is invoked, just return from the function.  There is no need to do anything else.  Don't try to exit the entire process like your code is doing now.